# TableLayout not centered vertically

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a `TableLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` as one of its attributes, but it is not being centered vertically.

Here is my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/line_drawing_relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/activity_linking_tl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/table_row_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="1dp" >

            <com.xx.myview
                android:id="@+id/id_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <com.xx.myview
                android:id="@+id/id_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/line_drawing_b_restart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="22dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_restart" >
    </ImageButton>

<!-- There are more views/widgets here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had `android:layout_below="xxx"` as well (for some reason not shown in the code I posted), which overrode the centering I was trying to achieve. Removing this solved it.  Obvious really.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the RelativeLayout is taking up as much space as you think?  It might be that the TableLayout is centered, but that the RelativeLayout is wrapping content, so it ends up being centered but in a smaller container than you expected.  It's hard for me to gauge without seeing the RelativeLayout portion of the XML.

One way to check your layouts is to use the [developer option](http://www.howtogeek.com/129728/) "show layout bounds":

[image: Developer options with "show layout bounds" enabled]

It will give you a better idea of how your layouts are being constructed.  If you are running an older phone without this developer option, I would just start setting flat colors for View backgrounds (e.g. `android:background="#F00"`).

Comment: I have checked that the `RealtiveLayout` is filling the whole screen as wanted. I will add the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting parent RelativeLayout width and height to match_parent.

and add this to your TableLayout

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but it didn't help. I will add the whole layout file.